# Swagger Codegen CLI Java Client one access token per instance, not thread safe

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

I have openapi 3.0 specification.
Generated code by:

```
java -jar /usr/bin/swagger-codegen-cli-v3.jar generate -l java -i openapi_shop.yaml -o apishop -DhideGenerationTimestamp=true -c config_shop.json
```

If in 1 service now I want to call that api I need to do:

```
String accessToken = getUserAccessToken();
api.getApiClient().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Products response = api.productsGet();
```

but as you see what if 50 users concurrently will start to ping that api ? it will end up mixing access tokens there.
What is the correct way to use that auto generated client ?
What I see there are 2 options:

1. modify existing auto generated code and take token as a param in every method, and simply put it in headers at the end, like json body
2. create new instance every time, for every user's request ( which does not sounds good )

Maybe I miss something ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to create ApiClient for every request. The performance impact of it isn't as significant if you are reusing client implementation used under the hood (ex. webclient instance)

examples in GitHub repo mentions this recommendation

> It's recommended to create an instance of ApiClient per thread in a multithreaded environment to avoid any potential issue.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/java/retrofit2rx

Update : I’ve explained it in more detail with code example here - https://blog.ideaharbour.site/engineering/2024/03/16/how-to-relay-access-token-on-multi-threaded-openapi-generator-client/